# How to add a facebook input box into a webform using c# so it posts to my timeline?

Tags: c#, facebook, visual-studio, twitter

Im using visual studio and winforms and c#

I created an input box and a go button and placed a web broswer on the area, I want to type in the box a message press go and it sends it to my facebook timeline so when i type in facebook in my search box I made it opens facebook and I can see what I have posted. My search box is complete and working, I also want to do this for twitter.

Comment: I'm new at c# and visual studio so not sure where to start.